# Writing product orders to txt file in php

Tags: php, loops, session, file-io, foreach

I'm working on some code for an online store to write orders to a txt file once they have been placed.

To generate this string I am using the following code... However it is only writing the information for the very last item in the array. I know that this is because as it runs through the foreach loop it is discarding previous information but have not been able to think of a way to counter this.

Any suggestions of a different way to tackle this?

```
foreach($_SESSION['itemname'] as $key=>$value) {
    $output_products =""
    ."item: ". $_SESSION['itemname'][$key] ."\t"
    ."qty: ".$_SESSION['itemqty'][$key]."\t"
    ."price: ".$_SESSION['itemprice'][$key]."\t"
    ."Sub Total: ".$_SESSION['subtotal'][$key]."\t";
}
$output_string = ""
.$_SESSION['fname'] ."\t"
.$_SESSION['lname'] ."\t"
.$_SESSION['address'] ."\t"
.$output_products ."\t"
.$_SESSION['grandTotal']."\n";
```

Comment: don't use a txt file use a data base

Comment: Thanks. I am getting that as advice from lots of people. But first  I am trying to get my head around this loop issue

Comment: you wouldn't have the issue if you used a db :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change

```
foreach($_SESSION['itemname'] as $key=>$value) {
    $output_products =""
    ."item: ". $_SESSION['itemname'][$key] ."\t"
    ."qty: ".$_SESSION['itemqty'][$key]."\t"
    ."price: ".$_SESSION['itemprice'][$key]."\t"
    ."Sub Total: ".$_SESSION['subtotal'][$key]."\t";
}
```

to

```
$output_products ="";
foreach($_SESSION['itemname'] as $key=>$value) {
    $output_products .=""
    ."item: ". $_SESSION['itemname'][$key] ."\t"
    ."qty: ".$_SESSION['itemqty'][$key]."\t"
    ."price: ".$_SESSION['itemprice'][$key]."\t"
    ."Sub Total: ".$_SESSION['subtotal'][$key]."\t";
}
```

You can use `.=` for appending strings.

Comment: Thanks for that. I had thought of using += but knew that wouldn't work for a string and had been wracking my brain trying to work out what to use instead.